# Error in the code for writing an indicator

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write my own indicator and add an RSI indictor to it and I'm getting error.
I'm trying this on trading view and I read their documentation and tried to see here a solution but I didn't find.

In short, how can I just add RSI indictor that will work as a condition, meaning if RSI is above 70 and it's in the "goldBulishSignal" condition I should get an buying signal?

Thank you,

```
//@version=5
indicator("golddaniel20 strategy", overlay= true)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
oversold = ta.rsi(70, 14)


goldBulishSignal = low[1] < low[2] and close[1] > close[2] and high > high[1] and rsi > oversold
plotshape(goldBulishSignal,             location  = location.belowbar,
             text  = "Bulish\nGold",    textcolor = color.black, 
             style = shape.labelup ,    color     = color.green, offset=-1)



goldBearishSignal= high[1] > high[2] and close [1] < close[2] and low < low[1]
plotshape(goldBearishSignal,            location  = location.abovebar,
             text  = "Bearish\nGold",   textcolor = color.black, 
             style = shape.labeldown,   color     = color.red  , offset=-1)



engulfingBullishSignal = high[1] > high [2] and close[1] > open  [2]
                       
plotshape(engulfingBullishSignal,           location  = location.belowbar,
             text  = "Bulish\nEngulfing",   textcolor = color.black, 
             style = shape.labelup ,        color     = color.green, offset=-1)



engulfingBearishSignal = high[1] > high [2] and close[1] <  open [2] 
                        
plotshape(engulfingBearishSignal,           location  = location.abovebar,
             text  = "Bearish\nEngulfing",  textcolor = color.black, 
             style = shape.labeldown,       color     = color.red  , offset=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

This `oversold = ta.rsi(70, 14)` doesn't make any sense. The first argument of the `rsi()` function is source which you correctly use before this line. It should be `oversold = 70` in your example.

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
oversold = input.float(70.0, "Oversold")

goldBulishSignal = low[1] < low[2] and close[1] > close[2] and high > high[1] and rsi > oversold
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! 
I tried this line of code, and it works, the problem is that it's doesn't show me on the chart when it's above 70. I did made some changes but when I can see clearly that the RSI above 70 it doesn't show that for some reason.

Comment: Well, then it must be one of other conditions that is `not true`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understood, I try to look at the and I change this line:
"indicator("golddaniel20 strategy", overlay= not true)"

But still it doesn't solve the problem, I does make some changes but for some reason they are wrong..

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. One of this `low[1] < low[2]`, this `close[1] > close[2]`, or this `high > high[1]` must be false.